# Object oriented how do frameworks invoke child classes ?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

I often use a framework that allow you to inherit from a certain class, and override a method there, and it will be invoked.

from the framework point of view, how is it done ? what pattern is this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are using a programming language / platform which provides metadata for the code. The metadata is used by the framework to find any classes which implement the certain class.

It's not a specific design pattern (not one that I know of in any way) but a technique which can be applied in most modern languages. For instance, ASP.NET uses this for it's `global.asax` file (and I use it in a .NET framework of mine).

It's typically used for application entry points to control the lifetime of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure in what context you are using the word framework, but what you describe sounds like `polymorphism`.